# Field names in report when Using Metadata API

Tags: reporting, metadata-api, fields, custom-report-type, report-builder

I Use the Metadata API to read, analyze, edit and create/update  reports.

I noticed that the field names (when specifying columns, filters, and groupings) which are returned when reading are not always the same names, and seem to depend upon **Report Type**.

Suppose I create a simple report on accounts, 
 and I only return two columns, Account owner and Account Name.

1. If I chose standard system-generated "Accounts" report types when creating this report, then upon reading it in the metadata API the column names are

   **ACCOUNT.NAME, USERS.NAME**
2. If I chose custom report type which I created manually, then the column names are (These seem to be the API names)

   **Account.Name, Account.Owner.Name**
3. If I choose a system-generated report type where account is not the main object, for example "Activities with Account" I get the following column names:

   **ACCOUNT.NAME, ACCOUNT_OWNER_NAME**

This happens with other (not custom) columkn as well.
Maybe there are even more possible column names for the same column in different report types, I don't know...

How to know when to use which names?
Also, Is there a way I read the other (besides API, option 2) column names programmatically? Can't find these names in the describe when using Partner or REST API.

Comment: I just asked this question [over here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/166405/list-of-names-of-standard-fields-as-seen-in-report-layout-metadata?noredirect=1&lq=1).  I got an unsatisfying answer.